# Laravel parent parameter in the relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Good afternoon I ran into a problem

database structure

**langs**

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ru |
| 2 | en |

**articles**

| id | alias |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test_article_1 |
| 2 | test_article_2 |

**article_lang**

| article_id | lang_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

**article_title_lang**

| article_id | lang_id | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | novost_1 |
| 2 | 1 | novost_2 |
| 1 | 2 | article_1 |
| 2 | 2 | article_2 |

models:

**Langs**

```
public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Articles::class, 'article_lang', 'lang_id', 'article_id');
    }
```

**Articles**

```
public function articleTitleLang()
    {
//        return $this->hasOne(ArticlesTitleLang::class, 'article_id', 'id')->where('lang_id', '=', 1); // i can get titles lang 1
//        return $this->hasOne(ArticlesTitleLang::class, 'article_id', 'id')->where('lang_id', '=', 2); // i can get titles lang 2


        return $this->hasOne(ArticlesTitleLang::class, 'article_id', 'id'); // always lang id 1 (because the relation has one)
    }
```

in controller:

```
$articles = Langs::with([
            'articles',
            'articles.articleTitleLang'
        ])->get();
        return response($articles, 200)
```

return json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "ru",
    "articles": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "alias": "test_article_1",
        "pivot": {
          "lang_id": 1,
          "article_id": 1
        },
        "article_title_lang": {
          "title": "novost_1",
          "article_id": 1,
          "lang_id": 1,
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "alias": "test_article_2",
        "pivot": {
          "lang_id": 1,
          "article_id": 2
        },
        "article_title_lang": {
          "title": "novost_1",
          "article_id": 2,
          "lang_id": 1,
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "en",
    "articles": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "alias": "test_article_1",
        "pivot": {
          "lang_id": 2,
          "article_id": 1
        },
        "article_title_lang": {
          "title": "novost_1",
          "article_id": 1,
          "lang_id": 1,
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "alias": "test_article_2",
        "pivot": {
          "lang_id": 2,
          "article_id": 2
        },
        "article_title_lang": {
          "title": "novost_2",
          "article_id": 2,
          "lang_id": 1,
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to change the dynamic value in the Articles model depending on the parent language value, so that when the language value is "en", the result is "title" = article_1, article_2

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, in `Articles` Model

```
public function articleTitleLang()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ArticlesTitleLang::class, 'article_id', 'id')
    ->where('lang_id', $this->lang_id)->first();
}
```

Comment: if i use this construct return 500 error "message": "Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null",

```
```

Comment: if i dump object $this i get:
```
  table: "articles"
  fillable: array:4 [
    0 => "id"
    1 => "alias"
    2 => "published"
    3 => "publication_date"
  ]
```